# get-value project returns "unset"

Tags: gcloud

I am trying to follow the tutorial on how to start up a gcloud cloud service.

https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/quickstart-build

In order to build a docker project I need to run this command.

```
gcloud config get-value project
```

This supposedly gives me the project-id which I am supposed to use in the next step.

However I get "(unset)" which I cannot use this in the next step :

[image]

How do I set my project-id? This tutorial seems to be wrong.

Comment: The tutorial misses this step. Please consider providing feedback on that tutorial page so that Google can address this. Perhaps share @Asdfg answer so that they can include it or something similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gcloud projects list` will give you the list of projects. Find the project id from that list and use it in `gcloud config set project <projectid>`.

If you don't get the list of projects, use `gcloud auth login` to login to your GCP account and then execute above commands.

Comment: thanks! yes. set-value didnt work for me but "set" did. "gcloud config set project <projectid>"